# model.$modelValue is NaN in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bENp/66/

If you look at the JavaScript console, you'll see something like this:

```
TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'replace'
    at makeHtml (https://raw.github.com/coreyti/showdown/master/compressed/showdown.js:62:705)
    at render (http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:50:42)
    at link (http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:54:13)
    at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:42:321)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:38:198)
    at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:42:261)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:38:198)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:37:332
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:15:440
    at Object.e.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:85:416) <markdown ng-model="someCode" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> angular.min.js:60
```

The problem is that `model.$modelValue` is `NaN` when its type shouldn't even be a number. Nevertheless, the markdown renders. I could add a `typeof model.$modelValue == 'string'` check, but I'd rather treat the underlying cause. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem in your directive is that angular triggers the watch once before the expression has been evaluated. So the very first time the value is `undefined`. I don't believe that can be prevented, but is how AngularJS works.

I added a `val` parameter to your render function to show the actual watched value (logged to the console--see the fiddle at the bottom). The `ngModelController` [initializes `$modelValue` to NaN](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.6/src/ng/directive/input.js#L879), that's why `NaN` is passed to the function instead of `undefined`.

But since it seems as if the `makeHtml` function expects a string, an easy fix is to pass it an empty string if the value is falsy (might be even better to convert it to a string).

```
var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(model.$modelValue || '');
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bENp/179/).

Comment: Thanks Martin. Good to know this.

Comment: Thank you very much. And have to say that it's very counter-intuitive behavior, I spent a hour in console where I saw value but my code - not.

Answer (score 30):

I was not aware that $modelValue was initialized to NaN and ran into a similar issue. If the $modelValue is really needed at initialization, a solution may be to watch it until it has been assigned a new value:

```js
.directive('contentEditor', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel){

            var unregister = $scope.$watch(function(){
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, initialize);

            function initialize(value){
                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                unregister();
            }

            //...
        }
    };
});
```

The $watch returns a deregistration function, so it can be unregistered as soon as a new value has been assigned to $modelValue.

Comment: I didn't understand how did that work, but it worked. :)

Comment: Very helpful and correct work with ngModelController

Comment: When the return value of the first function changes, the second function runs. `NaN` is never equal to `NaN` (why it's default), so `initialize` always runs after the first model change.

Answer (score 21):

I think you can also wrap it in a `ngModel.$render` function.

Like so:

```
.directive('classOnValue', function($timeout) {
           return {
               restrict: 'A',
               require: 'ngModel',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                   ngModel.$render = function(){
                       //Do something with your model
                       var actualValue = ngModel.$modelValue;
                   }

               }}
       })
```

Comment: Voting up this answer. For those want to interact with the model you can have the actual model value without errors.

Comment: it fixed my issue as well!!

Answer (score 4):

Another variant (just if somebody will find that question here): just wrap execution of directive in $timeout function. As example, my directive which use it:

```
.directive('classOnValue', function($timeout) {
               return {
                   restrict: 'A',
                   require: 'ngModel',
                   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                       $timeout(function() {
                           var value = (attrs.value || ngModel.$modelValue || ngModel.$viewValue );
                           if (value) {
                               element.addClass(attrs.classOnValue);
                           }
                       });
                   }}
           })
```

Comment: Since ngModel is made facultative, errors may occur unless a check is made, such as : `if (!ngModel) {return;}`.

Comment: @timmy because timeout will be called in digest cycle of Angular.

Comment: Where in the digest cycle will the code be executed?  I couldn't find any docs on this.  How did someone even know how to perform this technique?  Seems like magic if one doesn't understand the cycle and how to tap into it :)

Comment: It's a good solution, better then using watches. Using timeouts is actually an ok, and angular-style.