# When is $render() of ngModel called with real data?

Tags: angularjs, nan

I am writing a directive to cooperate with ngModel.  As shown in the example, I set the $render function on the controller to my function.

When the code initializes, it is invoked twice, the first time with $modelValue and $viewValue set to NaN, and then a second time with the actual value of the model.

The problem is, NaN is a bear to test for.  The function `isNaN()` is worthless, so far as I can see (it returns false for `[""]` but true for `["."]`) and `Number.isNaN()` is not widely supported.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, is the question really how to determine that `NaN` is `NaN`?

Comment: Hmm, should be undefined for the first call.

Comment: you didn't list the example you mention, but what is the directive doing that it needs to be in the middle of the `$render` cycle in the first place?

Comment: @NewDev -- "How to determine that `NaN` is `NaN`?" is the $64,000 question but the answer seems to be, you don't.  If something passes `angular.isNumber()` but not `isFinite()` then it is definitely NaN.  Or one of the infinities...

Comment: @rbaghbanli -- no, it's undefined in the second call if the model is undefined.

Comment: @Claies -- I am trying to provide a default value if the model value is set, but invalid.

Comment: @Malvolio, I'm not sure how you are getting `NaN` - in a trivial case ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TKD8wpAbsxY2SKhqk85h?p=preview)) if model is not set, it is `undefined`. Off-topic, but setting a default value doesn't seem to me like the right thing to do. A model is what drives the View - not the other way around. Take `<select>` for example - it has a specific behavior when the model is not among valid options.

Comment: @NewDev -- your example proves that *in some cases*, the modelView is `undefined`, not in every case. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16384177/238884) shows how `NaN` is also a possibility.  Your example makes the situation worse, because I cannot rely on the first call being "bad".

Comment: @Malvolio, ok, yes, `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` are `NaN` in the *very beginning* (during link-time), before `$formatters` run and before `$render` (which is why the example you provided has `NaN`). This example will help to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/WPR9oYTZ5IKWOLRUsSiw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a partial answer to my question, about [how to test for NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314447/how-do-you-test-for-nan-in-javascript), but it still seems awkward to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` of `ngModel` only ever assume (unless specifically assigned) the value of `NaN` in the *very beginning* - at link-time - and before any `$formatters`, `$render` and `$validators` (in that order) had a chance to run.

In other words, if you were to log at various points these values, you'd get the following (assuming the `ngModel` variable is set to `"foo"`):

```
              link-time    $formatters     $render     $validators
              -----------------------------------------------------
$modelValue     NaN           "foo"         "foo"         "foo"
$viewValue      NaN            NaN          "foo"         "foo"
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xoy4cFFgKKSkx2FoiMVp?p=preview)

In words, unless you need to access `ngModel` at `link`-time, there is no need to guard against `NaN`. Moreover, there is also no double invocation - the `ngModel` pipe runs once per change.

Given the [example you cite in comments](http://jsfiddle.net/8bENp/66/) my guess that you are seeing `NaN` in the `$render` function because you manually invoke the `$render` at link-time.

Comment: ngModel is only available to me at link-time.

Comment: Of course it is, but `$render` doesn't need to run at link time - `ngModel` runs it when model value changes or set for the first time

Comment: Dunno what to tell you.  ngModel _is_ running $render at link time, with the value set to NaN.

Comment: @Malvolio, try to repro then. The only other thing I can think of is that another directive that also does `require: "ngModel"` initiates rendering

Comment: They are input elements in a form -- doesn't Angular naturally require `ngModel` so as to keep the FormController up to date?

Comment: @Malvolio, yes, all input elements `require: "ngModel"`, but they also provide `$render`, so you shouldn't be re-defining it. `$render` should be defined if you are the one who implements the model-to-DOM translation. So, I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve