# How do you test for NaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nan

I have a variable x and I want to test if x is set to NaN.  How do I do that?

My first instinct is probably to, you know, test it, like this:

```
if (x === NaN) {  ...
```

Silly rabbit, no, that would be far too easy.  NaN is like NULL in SQL, it is not equal to anything, even itself.

But look, there is a function called `isNaN()` -- maybe that will do it!

No, so far as I can tell, `isNaN()` is utterly worthless.

For example, `isNaN([""])` properly returns false, but `isNaN(["."])` returns true.  You don't want do know how I learned about this flaw.

How do I do this?

Turns out, my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript), but the selected answer is wrong. The [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988441/238884) has 20% as many upvotes.

Comment: "*You don't want do know how I learned about this flaw.*" - I wonder why you would call `isNaN` on an array?

Comment: @Bergi -- I was writing a date-picker.  I almost punched the screen when `["2015", "05", "05"]` was marked as NaN.

Comment: But why are you expecting an array to behave like a number at all?

Comment: @Bergi -- I am not.  Angular is giving me NaN to mean "the data isn't available yet", and the actual data (which in this case is an array) when it is.  I need a way to know whether the data is there.

Comment: OK, then I'd rather use `Array.isArray` to detect the data, instead of detecting its absence.

Comment: @Bergi -- if you look at [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313950/when-is-render-of-ngmodel-called-with-real-data), you can see the issue: Angular calls ngModel.$render with NaN if the data isn't ready and with the data if it is.  The data is an array in one case, but there are lots of other cases.  Of course, there is no reason that NaN itself couldn't be a legal value...

Comment: As regards the answer to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment59397346_2652319), I was asking how to check that a *number* is NaN, not how to check whether *any* value is NaN. So I guess this question actually *isn’t* answered by the answers to mine, and thus isn’t a duplicate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The question has the answer if you read closely enough.  That is the way I found it: I was typing out the question and... bingo.

You remember when I wrote "`NaN` is like NULL in SQL, it is not equal to anything, even itself"?  So far as I know, `NaN` is the only value in Javascript with this property.  Therefore you can write:

```
var reallyIsNaN = function(x) {
   return x !== x;
};
```

Comment: After reading [MDN docs for Number.NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), it suggests to also check if `typeof x === "number"`.  `isNaN` is different in that it coerces the value to a number before comparing (`+[] == 0`, wat?)

Comment: @thgaskell When you say +[] == 0 what happens is that javascript tries to convert the first value of the array to integer. Try to call array[0] un an empty array and it will return undefined. This conversion is not equal that of parseInt and undefined will be converted to 0, try +[1] and + ['1223fsds']. Finally 0 == 0. That's why you get that result.

Comment: @thgaskell Yes I saw the video. It was hilarious. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325896/why-using-the-unary-operator-on-an-array-gives-inconsistent-results-in-javascr/30326359

Comment: @thgaskell - wat is not [wat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynENRrsjqqI).

Comment: Please keep calm and remember that Java, C#, Python, Scala, C++ (under clang, g++ and msvc) all have the same NaN behaviour as JavaScript. In all of those languages `0/0` is NaN and in all of them NaN is not equal to itself. It is simply [what the standard requires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum — Standards are not moral imperatives.  The usual arguments for adhering to the standards are (1) they represent Best Practices in the considered opinion of a group of experts and (2) they are what the user is likely to expect.  Neither of those obtain in this case.

Comment: Perhaps, but this is more of a CPU architecture problem than a JavaScript one - JavaScript is simply doing what every other language in the world is doing in this case.

Comment: What if x is "2"? This would fail. Because `x="2"; x !==x; // is false`

Answer (score 75):

**Short Answer**

For ECMAScript-5 Users:

```
#1
if(x !== x) {
    console.info('x is NaN.');
}
else {
    console.info('x is NOT a NaN.');
}
```

For people using ECMAScript-6:

```
#2
Number.isNaN(x);
```

And For consistency purpose across ECMAScript 5 & 6 both, you can also use this [polyfill for Number.isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Polyfill)

```
#3
//Polyfill from MDN
Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && isNaN(value);
}
// Or
Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(value) {     
    return value !== value;
}
```

**Note: I prefer to test using #1 which works same all places and does not have dependency on latest JS also. *(It always gives me correct result. No surprises!)***

---

**Detailed Explanation:**

Here is our awesome NaN

```
NaN == NaN; // false
NaN === NaN; // false
```

*Please don't blame `JavaScript` for this, it is NaN which is supposed to behave this way in other languages also Which is fine as per [rationale for all comparisons returning false NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/893612)*

So comes `isNaN` as our savior, but wait it acts little differently in some scenarios like

```
isNaN(undefined); // true
isNaN({});        // true
isNaN("lorem ipsum"); // true
```

I had some strange faces by seeing the results above. And here comes reason from MDN

> When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN.

So how should we test NaN for the non-numbers variables at all? I always go by the following

```
if(x !== x) {
    console.info('Is a NaN');
}
else {
    console.info('Not a NaN');
}
```

**ECMAScript-6/JavaScript-2015 Updates**

Do we have anything in ECMAScript-6 for the same. Yup we do...

```
Number.isNaN(x); // true
```

The ES6 implementation will also be helpful for the above cases like

```
Number.isNaN(undefined); // false
Number.isNaN({}); // false    
Number.isNaN("lorem ipsum"); // false
```

whereas ECMAScript-5 global function `isNaN` outputs in `true` for the above cases, which sometimes may not align with our expectation.

Comment: like `isNaN( "" ) = false` and `isNaN( {} ) = true` while `Number.isNaN( "" ) = false` and `Number.isNaN( {} ) = false`

Comment: Polyfill could also be as simple as `Number['isNaN'] || (Number.isNaN = function(a) { return a !== a });` Basically the same, minus a handful or so of chars and with the variable set moved to the other side of the operator.

Comment: Read more about isNaN() here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an overkill but how about trying this?:

```
if (Number(dataInput) !== Number(dataInput))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).