# Why using the unary operator + on an array gives inconsistent results in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was doing some testing converting values to integer in javascript and printing the output in the console when I came across with this strange behavior.

```
console.log(+[]) ==> 0
console.log(+[123]) ==> 123
console.log(+['123']) ==> 123
console.log(+[123, 456]) ==> NaN
console.log(+['123asdf']) ==> NaN
```

I thought the values were being converted using parseInt but turns out it wasn't so I went to  the javascript conversion table http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

This give me a better idea on how conversions are performed. Acording to this table

```
[] => 0
[20] => 20
[10,20] => NaN
["twenty"] =>NaN
["ten","twenty"] => NaN
```

So aparently they take the first value of the array and convert it using the specified rules. The rules of parseInt does not apply.

I tested to reach this conclusion. You can nested it all you want, it will give you the same result.

```
console.log(+[[[[[[[[[[[10]]]]]]]]]]]) => 10
```

So then I thought, ok if that's the case

```
console.log(+[undefined]) will return NaN
console.log(+[null]) will return 0
console.log(+[false]) will return 0
```

those are the values expected from the javascript conversion table to integer but turns out

```
console.log(+[undefined]) => 0
console.log(+[null]) => 0
console.log(+[false]) => NaN
```

The last is the most strange because false is converted to 0, not to NaN.
Can someone explain the strange behaviour or explain how this conversion is performed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Unary + operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) internally uses the *ToNumber* abstract operation.

The [*ToNumber* abstract operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), when applied to objects, calls the object's `toString` method (by way of the [`[[DefaultValue]]` internal method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)) and then re-applies the *ToNumber* operation on the resulting string representation.

The interesting thing here is Array's `toString` method. Note that `[false].toString()` is quite different from `[undefined].toString()` or `[null].toString()`. When we inspect the specification for [`Array.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2), we see that internally it uses [`Array.prototype.join`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5). Step 8 of the `join` algorithm says:

> 8. If *element0* is `undefined` or `null`, let *R* be the empty String; otherwise, Let *R* be *ToString*(*element0*).

Thus, any array containing a single `null` or `undefined` stringifies to the empty string (which *ToNumber* number-ifies to `0`), while other values will stringify to some other string (which will then number-ify to `NaN` if the string is non-numeric).

`+[undefined]` is the same as `+""`, while `+[false]` is the same as `+"false"`.

Comment: Hah, you got there faster than me. I was just about done with `GetValue` and on my way through `ToNumber`. The ECMA spec is surprisingly hard to read.