# How do I make javascript if statement not accept anything besides numeric values

Tags: javascript, html

How would integrate text as an argument for my if statement to function?

```js
function ifStatement() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userBlank").value;
  if (userInput > 9) {
    return alert("Please enter a correct value");
  } else {
    document.write("you may enter");
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="ifStatement();">
  <input id="userBlank" type="text">
</form>
```

As seen here, I want my if statement to be triggered off of text as well as numbers less than 9. Is it possible to do that?

I tried putting text into the input blank however it did not trigger the if statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314447/how-do-you-test-for-nan-in-javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger"?  You specified an `onclick` to call `ifStatement` for the *button*.

Comment: have a look at `parseInt()` to see what it does - break the problem down into stages, like 1) is there an input? 2) Is it a number? 3) Is it in range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Answer (score 1):

IIUYC, you can achieve that without JS using [`number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) input type:

```
<input id="userBlank" type="number" min="0" max="9" required>
```

It won't allow you to enter anything besides digits and input's value will be checked on submit so it's not less than 0 and not greater than 9.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your data types

```
document.getElementById("userBlank").value
```

is going to return a string but you want to compare it with a number.

Try to normalize your data contained in 'userInput' first maybe using something like parseInt() so you can compare these two values.

Answer (score 0):

Freshly tried:

```
function ifStatement() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userBlank").value;
    if ( (isNaN(userInput)) || ((!isNaN(userInput)) && (userInput > 9)) ) {
        console.log("Please enter a correct value");
    } else {
        console.log("you may enter");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) to create custom validation. To check whether it's a single digit number, you can use the regular expression `\d` (short for digit). You can use the `title` attribute to add a custom tooltip message when validation fails and you can use the [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required) to ensure this field isn't blank. In the end, this looks like:

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('success');return false">
    <input type="text" pattern="\d" required="required" title="A single digit number is required" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can test input values by using regex, but as already noted HTML5 does much of this for you; Giving no reason to do it in javascript for on page form testing.

But it is still useful for testing query string data on the URL, localStorage data, or cookie data.

```
function ifStatement() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userBlank").value;
  if (/[0-9]/.test(userInput)) {
    alert("You entered: " + userInput);
  } else {
    alert("Enter a number");
  }
}
```

Also note, javascript testing on the page does not protect the server from bad user input data. Anyone can simply go into inspect page tools and remove the test and allow bad data to be sent to a server.