# If I have something that evaluates to NaN why doesn't it show equality to NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

In the following code:

```
var notNum = 'dfsd'
Number(notNum) === NaN
```

The last expression evaluates to false. Do you know why? Is there no way to use NaN in a comparison?

```
typeof(Number(notNum)) === 'number'
```

This somehow evaluates to true. I really don't understand how NaN works..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

Comment: From the [MDN page on NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN): "`NaN` compares unequal (via `==`, `!=`, `===`, and `!==`) to any other value -- including to another `NaN` value."

Comment: If you're looking to check whether a value is `NaN` --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314447/how-do-you-test-for-nan-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

NaN (Not-a-Number) is a global object in JS returned when some mathematical operation gets failed.

You can't compare an object with another object directly.
Either you have to use typeof which you are using or you can use Object.is()

Object.is(Number(notNum), NaN) // true