# AngularJS - add all values in table row dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having a table where the user will enter data in the fields when they enter each value in each cell, the last cell needs to be updated with its total. with this snippet I'm getting `45+90+36`. I know its easy with jQuery, but I wanted to do this as simple as possible in Angular.

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="4"><span class="textRotate">TESTING</span>
  </td>
  <td>XXXX</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxPrevention">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxAppraisal">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxInternalFailure">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxxExternalFailure">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxPerformance">NA</td>
  <td ng-model="tableVal.xxxTotal">{{tableVal.xxxxPrevention + tableVal.xxxxAppraisal}}</td>
  <td>%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
<tr>
  <td rowspan="4"><span class="textRotate">TESTING</span>
  </td>
  <td>XXXX</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxPrevention">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxAppraisal">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxInternalFailure">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxxExternalFailure">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="text" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxPerformance">NA</td>
  <td ng-model="tableVal.xxxTotal">{{ (tableVal.xxxxPrevention|number) -- (tableVal.xxxxAppraisal|number)}}</td>
  <td>%</td>
</tr>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: one more doubt. when the value entered in text box crosses 4 digits its saying NAN why?

Comment: Try changing the expression to "{{ (tableVal.xxxxPrevention) -- (tableVal.xxxxAppraisal)}}" . It works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383767/model-modelvalue-is-nan-in-directive, read this for further details.

Comment: thanks it works and tableVal.xxxTotal is not getting the current total, when in console.log it prints undefined, any idea on that?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

**Solution 1:**

You can make your `type` of `input` as `number` instead of `text` (for HTML 5):

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="4"><span class="textRotate">TESTING</span>
  </td>
  <td>XXXX</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="number" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxPrevention">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="number" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxAppraisal">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="number" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxInternalFailure">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="number" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxxExternalFailure">$</td>
  <td>
    <input id="testingInput" type="number" ng-model="tableVal.xxxxPerformance">NA</td>
  <td>{{tableVal.xxxxPrevention + tableVal.xxxxAppraisal}}</td>
  <td>%</td>
</tr>
```

**Solution 2**:

Use the `parseInt()` method before sum:

```
<td>{{parseInt(tableVal.xxxxPrevention) + parseInt(tableVal.xxxxAppraisal)}}</td>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, solutions 2 doesn't work, but solution 1 works fine

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `$scope.$watch()`.

Ex.

```
$scope.$watch('tableVal', function (nV, oV) {
    // nV == new value, oV == old value
    if (nV != oV) {
        // Run some function here to update total and assign it to $scope.property
    }
}, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a method on `$scope` to calculate the numbers by passing the `ng-model` to that method:

```js
$scope.tableVal.xxxtotal = function(){
    return (+$scope.tableVal.xxxxPrevention) + (+$scope.tableVal.xxxxAppraisal);
}
```

and in the view update this td:

```
<td>{{ tableVal.xxxTotal(); }}</td>
```

Usage of `ng-model` directive on `td` is useless. That should only be used on input elements.

A simple test snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
      test1: "",
      test2: "",
      total:function(){
         return (+$scope.obj.test1) + (+$scope.obj.test2);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='appCtrl'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='obj.test1'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='obj.test2'>
  <pre>{{ obj.total(); }}</pre>
</div>
```